# How can I search for siblings using linq?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

Given the following XML (which are two rows in an Excel XML datasheet) I want to find all of the **Cost** values and find the associated **AltID**

```
...
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String" AltID="1" ColumnHeader="AltName">Alternative 2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number" ColumnHeader="Total">0.105468638</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="Number" ColumnHeader="Cost">123</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="Number" ColumnHeader="Risk">456</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String" AltID="2" ColumnHeader="AltName">Alternative 3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number" ColumnHeader="Total">1.7803949999999999</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="Number" ColumnHeader="Cost">123</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="Number" ColumnHeader="Risk">456</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
...
```

I can find the Costs easy enough, but I need to find a way to say, with this given cost, go "up" a level to **Row**, then find the cell whose **ColumnHeader** equals AltName, and then give me the **AltID** attribute.

```
    Dim costs = From item In dg...<Table>...<Row>...<Cell>...<Data> Select item Where item.@ColumnHeader = "Cost"
    For Each i In costs
        dim CostValue as Integer = i.value
        dim AltID as Integer = ...
    Next
```

Comment: Why do want to use linq? Why don't you use a simple XPath query?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the triple dot to navigate through each of the elements. Triple dot is shorthand for .Descendents. You can simplify this to just dg... as long as you don't care where in the heirarchy the Data node lies. Once you get the node(s) you want, you can navigate back up the graph using Parent and then back down again as necessary. This should give you the AltID attribute for the given node:

```
 Dim costs = From item In dg...<Data> 
    Where item.@ColumnHeader = "Cost"
    select item.Parent.Parent...<Data>.
               FirstOrDefault(Function(node) node.Attribute("ColumnHeader").Value = "AltName").@AltID
```

Alternatively, you may be able to use the Ancestors rather than .Parent.Parent to achieve the same goal. See http://www.dbtalks.com/uploadfile/a7e1c8/linq-to-xml-axis-methods-part-1-ancestors-and-ancestorsands/ .